# Moved with my girlfriend for her new job, I paid moving expenses, which she later repaid. Can she claim moving deduction? (USA)

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, moving

Moved with my girlfriend for her new job, I paid moving expenses, which she later repaid. Can she claim the moving deduction? (We're in the US)

Comment: Did she repay you in the same year?

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, the repayment was in the same year, less than a month from my original payments